# What does it mean to create an iOS module in 'Library Mode'?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am quite new to application development on iPhone, so please forgive me if the question seems to tedious.

I have been asked to create an app with a module that uses "Library Mode", and that somehow by doing so, the module will not need to be signed. I have done a lot of searching on the Internet and asking my fellow developers. No one has a clue what it actually means.

So my questions are simply:

1. What does it mean to create an app in "Library Mode"?
2. If I create the app in "Library Mode", is it true that I will not have to sign it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are being asked to [create a static library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/AA-Developing_a_Static_Library_and_Incorporating_It_in_Your_Application/archiving_an_application_that_uses_a_static_library.html), not the end application.

So your code will be signed by the party that uses your library in their app. And therefore you don't have to sign it yourself.

Make sense?

By the way, I found a [blog post](http://blog.pioneeringsoftware.co.uk/2011/08/05/developing-a-project-as-an-os-x-framework-and-ios-static-library-at-the-same-time) that looks useful as you head down this path.

Comment: Thank you. It really does make sense. And thanks for the useful links as well. :)